# intersections of powers of maximal ideal in integral domain

Tags: complex-analysis, field-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}$ be a disc. $p\in \Omega$.

In the integral domain $R=H(\Omega)$ " the space of holomorphic functions in $\Omega$, consider the maximal ideal $M_p=\{f \in R : f(p)=0\}$.

I need to find

$\cap_{n \geq 1}{M_p}^n$. (This intersection is the Jacobson ideal, isn't it?)

Here, ${M_p}^n$ is the nth power of $M_p$.

My thought, and according to the Krull Intersection Theorem, the intersection is the zero ideal. Even the theorem assumes that the ring is Notherian, but in my question $R$ is integral domain.
Anyway, If $f \in \cap_{n \geq 1}{M_p}^n$ then $f \in {M_p}^n$ for all $n$. Does that mean that $f=0$ as $f(p)=\cdots =f^{(n)}(p)=0$?
I think $\{{M_p}^n\}$ is increasing sequence in ideals.

Comment: Is $M_p^n$ the $n$-th power of $M_p$ as an ideal or is it notation for something else?

Comment: yes, it is the nth power of $M_p$ as an ideal.

Comment: If you can show that $f \in M_p^{n+1}$ implies $f^{(n)} \in M_p$, then the series expansion of $f$ around $p$ must vanish (all its coefficients do). Hence $f$ is zero in a neighbourhood of $p$. This implies $f \equiv 0$ by the identity theorem.

Comment: Also note that the sequence of ideals is not increasing, othewise the intersection would be just $M_p$. We have $M_p^{n+1} \subset M_p^n$. Moreover, you are not intersecating all maximal ideals, in fact, the only maximal ideal in the intersection is $M_p$. This *happens* to be the Jacobson radical (since $J(R) \subset \cap_q ev_q^{-1}(0) = \{0\}$), though.

Comment: That being said, I haven't checked wether $f \in M_p^{n+1}$ indeed implies $f^{(n)}\in M_p$. It does for $n = 2$.

Comment: I already checked it and it holds. Thank you very much!

Comment: Note that $\mathcal{H}(\Omega)$ is not noetherian, by Weierstrass's factorization theorem for holomorphic functions